# Plot pch conditionally with stripchart in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm having trouble plotting different symbols by trying to specify `pch` in `stripchart` in R:

```
set.seed(7)
(x <- rpois(20, 5))
stripchart(x, method = "jitter", pch = ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, 16, 17))
```

[image]

I'd like circles (`pch = 16`) for that are even, and triangles (`pch = 17`) for points that are odd. Should be simple but I can't get it to work -- it seems to be taking the first value only. I also can't look at the source code for `stripchart`.

Any suggestions? I'd prefer it if I could use base graphics rather than ggplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the vector by odd or even numbers and then plot the points twice with different `pch` values.

```
set.seed(7)
(x <- rpois(20, 5))

x1 <- x[x %% 2 == 0]
x2 <- x[x %% 2 != 0]

stripchart(x1, method = "jitter", pch = 16, xlim = range(x))
stripchart(x2, method = "jitter", pch = 17, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: this is helpful, but I made my reprex a bit too simplistic. I'm actually hoping to base `pch` off of a different vector of values rather than just their x value... I can edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: @eKoontz If possible, please ask a new question with realistic reproducible example and clear description.

Comment: You could split into a list and then use `Map` if there are many groups `lst <- split(x, (x > 0.5) + 1);
invisible(Map(stripchart, lst, add = c(FALSE, TRUE), method = "jitter", pch = list(17, 16), xlim = list(c(0, 1))));
> abline(v = 0.5, lty = 2)`

Comment: @akrun for my actual data, each point will be plotted based on a separate value rather than it's actual position in the plot -- I've edited my question to reflect that. `Map` might be helpful yet though

Comment: @eKoontz  Have you tried the `Map` approach `lst <- split(x, as.integer(x %%2));invisible(Map(stripchart, lst, add = c(FALSE, TRUE), method = "jitter", pch = list(16, 17), xlim = list(range(x)));`

Comment: @eKoontz I have updated my answer for you. But please notice that if you have a new question, just ask the new question.

Comment: @www thanks, I tried to just clarify my question rather than ask a new one. It seems breaking it up into chunks is the way to go -- I've accepted your answer.